# Add and remove class using javascript on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add class via javascript on scroll. My issue is I need to add and remove class on reaching a particular section id

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 500) {
    $(".clearHeader1").removeClass("video-background");
    $(".clearHeader11").addclass("video-foreground");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="id1" class="clearHeader1 video-background"></section>
<section id="id2" class="clearHeader1"></section>
```

Comment: what is this if (scroll >= 500)  for?? are you assuming scoll>500 changes section?

Comment: Actually i am looking for that "if condition". That is if the scroll position is equal to section id1 then i need to add or remove a class. help me to write that if condition

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one**

```
if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('#id1').offset().top + $('#id1').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
              $("#id1").removeClass("active");
             console.log("removeClass");
             }else{
                console.log("addClass");
             $("#id1").addClass("active");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scroll =  $(this).scrollTop();
    var section1Height = $('#id1').offset().top + $('#id1').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight;
    if (scroll >= section1Height ) {
        $(".clearHeader1").removeClass("video-background");
        $(".clearHeader11").addclass("video-foreground");
      }

    }
```